# I would like to convert this Borland C++ code into workable Visual Studio C++ Code, Some Issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, borland-c++

I have some old Borland C++ source code that needs to be converted into Visual Studio C++ code. I got some of it working, however have hit a roadblock with some "const chars" and "unsigned chars". Notably the IP addressing and Port addressing (lines 15 - 28 and the error points to line 44)

```
    // test1.cpp 5/23/97

    // example Win32 C++ program to read registers from PLC via gateway

    // compile with BC45 or BC50
    // default settings for Win32 console app
    // empty DEF file

    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>



    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        if (argc < 5)
        {
            printf("usage: test1 ip_adrs unit reg_no num_regs\n"
                "eg test1 198.202.138.72 5 0 10\n");
            return 1;
        }
        char* ip_adrs = argv[1];
        unsigned short unit = atoi(argv[2]);
        unsigned short reg_no = atoi(argv[3]);
        unsigned short num_regs = atoi(argv[4]);
        printf("ip_adrs = %s unit = %d reg_no = %d num_regs = %d\n",
            ip_adrs, unit, reg_no, num_regs);

        // initialize WinSock
        static WSADATA wd;
        if (WSAStartup(0x0101, &wd))
        {
            printf("cannot initialize WinSock\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // set up socket
        SOCKET s;
        s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(502); // ASA standard port
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_adrs);
        int i;
        i = connect(s, (sockaddr*)& server, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        if (i < 0)
        {
            printf("connect - error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec = 5;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        // wait for permission to send
        FD_SET(s, &fds);
        i = select(32, NULL, &fds, NULL, &tv); // write
        if (i <= 0)
        {
            printf("select - error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // build request of form 0 0 0 0 0 6 ui 3 rr rr nn nn
        unsigned char obuf[261];
        unsigned char ibuf[261];
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) obuf[i] = 0;
        obuf[5] = 6;
        obuf[6] = unit;
        obuf[7] = 3;
        obuf[8] = reg_no >> 8;
        obuf[9] = reg_no & 0xff;
        obuf[10] = num_regs >> 8;
        obuf[11] = num_regs & 0xff;

        // send request
        i = send(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(obuf), 12, 0);
        if (i < 12)
        {
            printf("failed to send all 12 chars\n");
        }

        // wait for response
        FD_SET(s, &fds);
        i = select(32, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv); //read
        if (i <= 0)
        {
            printf("no TCP response received\n");
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // read response
        i = recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(ibuf), 261, 0);
        if (i < 9)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                printf("unexpected close of connection at remote end\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("response was too short - %d chars\n", i);
            }
        }
        else if (ibuf[7] & 0x80)
        {
            printf("MODBUS exception response - type %d\n", ibuf[8]);
        }
        else if (i != (9 + 2 * num_regs))
        {
            printf("incorrect response size is %d expected %d\n", i, (9 + 2 * num_regs));
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < num_regs; i++)
            {
                unsigned short w = (ibuf[9 + i + i] << 8) + ibuf[10 + i + i];
                printf("word %d = %d\n", i, w);
            }
        }

        // close down
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
```

This is code to connect to a simulator, and the IP and socket values in here are incorrect. However that should not be the issue, it is the conversion of the "chars" that is the real roadblock. Any feedback is appreciated.

The correct destination for the IP is DESKTOP-E503UCE or 192.168.0.11 and the port listed under server settings is 502. Please note that the IP above is a local IP (my computer)

Additionally, the only error currently occurring is Code C4996 - 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or Inet_Pton() instead or define _WINSTOCK_DEPREACTED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings on line 44.

Comment: What exactly errors are outputted?

Comment: Hi Kolen! The answer below from Jorge fixed the issue I was having with those errors. However, I am now encountering some newer issues associated IP Connections. It seems when I fix one thing another goes wrong. I apologize if this is out of the scope of this site, I am looking for some insight as to how to convert/connect to this simulator.

Comment: TBH, that's socket code, and the socket code headers are in C. You should look at some socket programming tutorials like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/ or https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/sockets_server_client.php (high google links)

Comment: "*Additionally, the only error currently occurring is Code C4996*" - as the warning says, `inet_addr()` is deprecated, you should be using `inet_pton()` or `Inet_Pton()` instead, or else you can add a `#define _WINSTOCK_DEPREACTED_NO_WARNINGS` statement above the `#include <winsock2.h>` to disable the warning.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple fix - we can just add a `reinterpret_cast` on line 75 and again on line 93.

Line 70:

```
i = send(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(obuf), 12, 0); // Line 75
```

Line 86:

```
i = recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(ibuf), 261, 0); // Line 93
```

#### Why do we have to do this?

Borland let you play fast and loose with the rules, and it automatically did those casts for you.

These casts are safe, and won't invoke undefined behavior, but it's best to be explicit about them.

Comment: As far as the types are concerned, a `char name[]` is the same as a `char* name`, it's the `unsigned` keyword in the declarations that really needs to go, as an `unsigned char*` is not the same as a `char*`

Comment: They can be cast to each other safely, and there are cases where you'd want to use `unsigned char` instead of `char`. For example, overflow is UB for `char` but it's well-defined for `unsigned char`. Using the `reinterpret_cast` is the safest solution in this case.

Comment: As far as I am aware, `reinterpret_cast` is the most dangerous of casts. realistically though, he could also yeet the `printf`s in favor of `std::cout` (given Borland C++ never had `<iostream>` to work with)

Comment: `char` and `unsigned char` are guaranteed to be the same size, and it is guaranteed to be safe to cast between them

Comment: But if the unsigned char is over 127, it will become negative on a `reinterpret_cast`, removing any of the benefits of using an `unsigned char` in the first place. Safe does not mean correct.

Comment: It becoming negative is *fine* because the binary representation is identical. In most cases where `unsigned char` is used in place of `char`, they used `unsigned char` because they needed it to be positive (because it was being used as an index or something, such as for a hash function or a map or a trie), and the value wrapping around is irrelevant when converted to `char`.

Comment: @JorgePerez "*Borland let you play fast and loose with the rules, and it automatically did those casts for you*" - maybe in C, it could, but certainly not in C++, and I have never seen any Borland C++ compiler do what you claim. The OP's code should not have compiled in any C++ compiler, Borland or otherwise. The only way it could is if `send()` and `recv()` were declared with `void*` parameters instead of `char*` parameters